# Doing a dropdown button in css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to incorporate a dropdown button in my website but I don't know why the content of button is not showing correctly:

```
    <body> 
        <div class="topnav">
            <a id="inicio"  href="index.php">Inicio</a>
            <a id="contacto" href="login.php" >Login</a>
            <a id="contacto" href="registro.php">Registro</a>
            <a id="contacto" href="#" >Contacto</a>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
                <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#home">Iniciar sesion</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..">
        </div> 
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
</script>

    </body>
```

You can try the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/pgn6yw5f/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the background color of the dropdown-content a in your CSS-file. below is an example

```
dropdown-content a {
    /* Your other styling */
    background-color: inherit;
}
```

that solves the display issue.

Answer (score 1):

After some search

Here is an example of a drop-down menu using CSS only to improve performance

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

for more examples on CSS only dropdown menus look [HERE](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_dropdowns.asp)

Comment: Add :focus as well so mobile devices can use the menu too.